# Embed view block with JSON data output

Tags: views

How can I embed the output of a view in another page, as a JSON Data Document, without stopping the page processing ?

I have a view with format set to *JSON data document* and am attempting to embed the block output in a node with `views_embed_view('nec_map_data','block')`.

This embeds the block but with *Views API mode* unchecked page processing is stopped at the JSON and the page doesn't render.

If I enable Views API Mode then the block output is wrapped in a div.

I would like the JSON output from the view to be assigned to a javascript variable in the node. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by adding this function ( a customized version of the original views_json_get in the [view_datasource module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource) ) in your template or custom module

```
/**
 * Gets JSON data from a View rendered in the JSON data document style.
 *
 * This is useful for when working with a JSON view in code.
 *
 * @param $name
 *   The name of the view.
 * @param $display_id
 *   The display of the view to use.
 * @param $args
 *   The arguments to pass to the view.
 * @param $raw
 *   If TRUE, the JSON data is returned as a string.  Otherwise, an object
 *   representation is returned.
 * @return
 *   The JSON data in the form of an object or a string or NULL otherwise.
 */
function views_json_noheader_get($name, $display_id = 'default', $args = array(), $raw = FALSE) {
  $view = views_get_view($name);
  if (!is_object($view)) {
    return NULL;
  }

   $view->display[$display_id]->display_options['style_options']['using_views_api_mode'] = 1;

  $preview = $view->preview($display_id, $args);
  $start_pos = strpos($preview, '{');
  $finish_pos = strrpos($preview, '}');
  $length = $finish_pos - $start_pos + 1;
  $json = trim(substr($preview, $start_pos, $length));

  if ($raw) {
    return $json;
  }

  return json_decode($json);
}
```

and  get the result of your view  by typing in your function:

```
$json = views_json_noheader_get('yourviewname', 'yourview json display id', null, true);
```